# CreateProcessW failed 193 :flutter doctor

Tags: android, dart, flutter

> CreateProcessW failed 193
>   Unhandled exception:
>   ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: I have same problem with flutter run and in the gradle phase

Answer (score 1):

**Change your user folder this C:\Users\Sanjaya Jena to this C:\Users\Sanjaya**

Remove space from name of user folder(Sanjaya jena) and used the below youtube link to change your path name.

checkout this link https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What does this answer have to do with the question?

Comment: Change user folder name with out space and it works for me,

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the latest version of the android build tools, 29.0.2 in my case
https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools: download the latest,
extract the folder android-10 and paste in your directory
C:\Users[your user name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools or 
[your android studio directory]\Sdk\build-tools
rename the folder to the version you downloaded
e.g. 29.0.2 in my case
[latest build pasted and renamed to 29.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpeDi.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your user name contains a space

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15481
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18938

It might also be a certificate issue

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15014,

Comment: Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

  Command: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.EXE rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}

Comment: what is the meaning of this line and how to edit user name

Comment: A calculated path doesn't point to a an executable file because Flutter doesn't treat spaces correctly. I don't know how to change the user name. Please ask in Windows related forums.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by spaces in the path of the flutter SDK.

I got around this problem by copying the SDK to another location without spaces in the name ex. C:\Users\Public\flutter and changing the flutter SDK path setting in Android Studio to the new path.